# How to Check if the Mic is Plugged/Unplugged

Tags: delphi, microphone

How to check if the microphone is plugged/unplugged using Delphi?

Answer (score 4):

```
function WaveInDevicePresent: boolean;
begin
  result := waveInGetNumDevs > 0;
end;
```

(uses `MMSystem`)

Comment: @opc0de: That is because you always have some sort of waveform input device present. It might be just a driver, with no physically attached microphone (or maybe you are using a laptop with a built-in mic that *is* always present?). The term 'microphone' is, I think, not very well defined from the WinAPI point of view. In most cases, however, there are no input devices unless you attach a microphone. But in some cases, as in your case, the function will always return `true`.  Nevertheless, it will *never* return `false` if there is an attached microphone.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, anyway i think is the only way you can detect this +1.

Comment: This might actually work if you plugged in a USB mic. But for a local audio input jack, it just isn't possible in general.  (Some audio chipset hardware does have a way to detect that something was plugged into a particular jack on your motherboard or a PCI sound card, but that functionality is not surfaced in any STANDARDIZED way through the Windows API.)

Comment: @Warren P: It works on every computer I have tried it on, using the 3.5 mm microphone input (that is, no USB mic.).

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work on some computers. Because it returns a number of devices. it cannot determine the if it is a microphone or Line-in etc. However it can be list up by using the waveInGetDevCaps().  but some computers displays no "Microphone or Mic" caption only the BrandName.